# Biome-specific music with resource packs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-data-packs

So, I saw a suggestion on r/Minecraft talking about biome-specific music, and wondered if it was possible with resource packs? I doubt it is, but i know there are some Minecraft gods out there. I also have Optifine, if that's any help.

Comment: It is definitely possible, with a datapack. I think advancements can check for the biome you're in, but I don't know anything more specific. The wiki can probably help.

Comment: Yes, indeed: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Advancements/List_of_triggers#minecraft:location I might try to do this myself at a later point in time, but maybe this is already enough information for you to get started.

Comment: Thanks! I've never tried using datapacks before, but there's a first time for everything right?

Comment: if anyone knows any good tutorials or anything that can teach me to use datapacks, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a worthy challenge. Maybe I'll try it out sometime. To be honest, I don't see why this kind of thing couldn't be applied to more than just biomes; other trigger conditions are possible using datapacks besides biomes. The only problem would be transitioning between songs; as far as I know, there is no way to slowly quiet a sound down to start another song.

Comment: @4AC11 Try this: [link](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Data_pack)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way Minecraft resource packs work, no, it is not possible to create biome-specific music with resource packs alone. Minecraft activates the default music in certain situations (survival, creative, nether, credits), and the only thing a resource pack can do is change what music plays in these situations, not add new situations of music. You can, however, add custom sounds and music with resource packs that can be played with the /playsound command as well as other datapacks, which can run the command if a certain condition is true, like if the player is in a specific biome. [Trigger the Music](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/customization/trigger-the-music), a datapack & resource pack combination that I made a while ago, for example, does just this.

Comment: Please do not only give a link to the actual answer. That website or the page could be deleted or changed at any point. Please at least upload it somewhere where it can be archived on web.archive.org (which does not work on that website). To really follow the rules of this website, you must include the important parts in the answer itself.

Comment: I didn't make the datapack purely based upon or for this post, so archiving it would be just as illegitimate as downloading another program online and archiving that one just to answer a different question about "what software can help me solve this problem?" The rule you provided does not apply to including software inside of the post or increasing its permanence. Still, the answer I provided is a bit vague and doesn't actually answer the question, so I did rephrase the question to meet this quota.

Comment: "what software can help me solve this problem?" is off-topic on this site anyway. This sounds like a better answer now, downvote undone.